# Angular Run a single/group Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How to run a single test or a group of tests?

I've tried in src/test.ts with (for a single test)

(My home component is in app/pages/home)

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\home\.spec\.ts$/);
```

but it doesn't work

I mean the browser is run

but I've got

```
0 specs, 0 failures
```

Comment: If you are using angular-cli to launch your tests, you may want to see : 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3603

Comment: I just saw the issues but with require.context('./', true, /\home\.spec\.ts$/); doesn't work because I think not match exists (in the fie I've got a simple test)

Answer (score 1):

Your tests are made of a `describe` and one or several `it` like so

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should ...', done => {

  });
});
```

If you want to force a group, use `fdescribe`, and a test, use `fit`

```js
fdescribe('Forcing MyComponent', () => {
  it('should ...', done => {

  });
});

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  fit('forced should ...', done => {

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not what I'm looking for. I want to test a single file like home.component.spec.ts or a group of files

Comment: That's exactly the point of my answer. use `fdescribe` in all the files you want tested.